# Multiple view in one XIB File ( one window )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a FirstView.xib file that I already have coded.
this view has a UITableView that reads from a web service.

I also have a SecondView.xib.
The SecondView.xib has a default view. i want to split this view so i have two horizontal-splited views.
the top one is the default one that comes with the SecondView.xib and the bottom half i want it to be the view in FirstView.xib.

i tried to manually drag and drop a view in the SecondView.xib and resize it, then tried the following code in the SecondView.xib.

```
[MyView addSubview:FirstView.view];
```

but did not work.

Comment: i've edited the post, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste views. Simply open FistView.xib, select the view, copy it, then open SecondView.xib, and select the parent view you want it to go into, and paste it.